# How to add custom folder uploads to filetypes on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using the below code to move all PDF uploads on my Wordpress site to a specific folder

```
// Function to move PDF Uploads to specific folder

<?php

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse47415_pre_upload');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'wpse47415_post_upload');

function wpse47415_pre_upload($file){
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse47415_custom_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}

function wpse47415_post_upload($fileinfo){
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse47415_custom_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function wpse47415_custom_upload_dir($path){
    $extension = substr(strrchr($_POST['name'], '.'), 1);
    if (!empty($path['error']) || $extension != 'pdf') {
        return $path;
    } //error or other filetype; do nothing. 
    $customdir      = '/pdf';
    $path['path']   = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['url']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);
    $path['subdir'] = $customdir;
    $path['path'] .= $customdir;
    $path['url'] .= $customdir;
    return $path;
}

?>
```

I want to use the same code for DOCX and XLS files, but if I repeat the code Wordpress fails, what can I do to reuse this code for different filetypes

Answer (score 1):

Just account for these different file types in your function:

```
function wpse47415_custom_upload_dir($path){    
    $allowed_extensions = array('pdf', 'docx', 'xls');
    $extension = substr(strrchr($_POST['name'],'.'),1);

    // On error or other filetyp, do nothing
    if( !empty($path['error']) ||  !in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions) ) { 
        return $path;
    }  

    $customdir = '/' . $extension;  // dynamically generate the custom directory
    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir;  
    return $path;
}
```

If you need multiple extensions to go in the same directory, you can use a [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).